# If Statement for Collection Metafield - Shopify

Tags: if-statement, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

I have added a metafield to a collection within my Shopify store. I have a namespace, key, and value. I am looking for a liquid code snippet to check if the collection has a specific metafield key, and then if so, to output the assigned value.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
{% if relationship = collection.metafields.parent %}
    <span>{{ relationship.parent[value] }}</span>
 {% endif %}
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I could implement this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: What is inside of the variables `relationship`, `value` and `collection.metafields.parent`? Wouldn't `collecation.metafields.parent` just be the namespace and not a specific metafield?

Comment: Note: You can't assign variables inside an if statement in Liquid!

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you wanted to check for the existence of a metafield, or more specifically the existence of a value within a metafield, you could do:

```
{% if collection.metafields.parent['metafield_name'] %}
  <span>{{ collection.metafields.parent['metafield_name'] }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

This is taking the value of whatever is contained in the metafield and checking if it returns a truthy or falsey type value. If the value is truthy (if there's text in the metafield) it will then output that to the screen.

Comment: Since a blank metafield is false-y, you wouldn't need the `.size > 0` part, no?

Comment: @DaveB is there documentation around that, because anytime I `console.info()` an empty metafield all I get is emptiness?

Comment: I think console.log/info/warn will abort and not do anything if passed nothing. You could try `console.info({{ metafield | json }})` or `console.info('Metafield:', {{ metafield | json }})` to make sure something always prints to the console

Comment: The way I've been using it is `console.info('{{ metafield_blah }}')` which also never returns an empty console.info. The console.info just gets passed an empty string when there's nothing in the metafield. Which is what I meant by "emptiness" as in it doesn't say false-y or anything. It just returns nothing.

But either way, you're still right that the `.size > 0` is not required and OP could probably just stick with testing whether the value is truthy/falsey without using `.size`.

Comment: Updated my answer @DaveB to remove `.size` comparison.